# How to add URLs to link to other Salesforce objects in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, hyperlink, parent

I have some review objects that are linked to some Case objects in a master-detail relationship. [image]

I want to be able to create hyperlinks in my custom LWC components that link to the specific case such as the case "123" as shown below.
[image]

However, I am unable to do that as I only know how to extract the case id with my code as shown below

```
 @api recordId;
    
    @wire(getRecord,{
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields: [
            REVIEW_ID_FIELD,
            REVIEW_CASE_FIELD,
            REVIEW_REVIEWED_BY_FIELD
        ]
    })
    reviewRecord;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: REVIEW_OBJECT})
    reviewObjectInfo;

    get reviewCaseID(){

        let reviewCaseIDInformation = {
            label: '',
            value: ''
        }

        if(this.reviewObjectInfo.data && this.reviewRecord.data){
            reviewCaseIDInformation['label'] = this.rreviewObjectInfo.data.fields['Case__C'].label
            reviewCaseIDInformation['value'] = this.reviewRecord.data.fields['Case__C'].value
        }
        return reviewCaseIDInformation;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple SLDS to built output field of type hyperlink.

```
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-47">
            Input Label
        </label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <a onclick={handleNavigate}>Input Value</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and handle the onclick event of anchor tag in js file as below:-

```
handleNavigate() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.reviewCaseID.value,
            objectApiName: 'Case',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

The UI will look like this:-

[image]